# Trying to dispatch action in custom header to change screen, nothing happens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to dispatch an action to change my screen.

I have a few basic screens setup in my navigator:

```
const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
  Day: {screen: DayScreen},
  Month: {screen: MonthScreen},
  Year: {screen: YearScreen}
});
```

I have my action like so:

```
export const navigate = (routeName, params, action) =>
  NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName, params, action });
```

When I dispatch a hardcoded route from a picker in my customheader:

```
this.props.actions.navigate('Day');
```

To display a basic page:

```
const Day = () => {
return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, height: 500, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: 'blue' }}>
            <Text>Days test</Text>
      </View>
);
};

export default Day;
```

I would expect the page to change but nothing happens, the action seems to dispatch ok but nothing happens, I do not get any errors.

Any ideas how I can change screens from my custom header?

**UPDATE**: I have tried to intergrate redux, however, I get the error:

**C:\sites\rgcalendar\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:73 TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of undefined
This error is located at:
    in Transitioner (at CardStackTransitioner.js:49)
    in CardStackTransitioner (at StackNavigator.js:60)
    in Unknown (at createNavigator.js:52)**

```
// navigationStack
import { StackNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import HomeScreen from "../components/HomeScreen";
import Day from "../components/calendar/Day";

const navigator = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: HomeScreen
  },
  Day: {
    screen: Day
  }
});

export default navigator;
```

Here is my Navigation reducer:

```
import AppNavigator from "../navigation/navigationStack";

const initialState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(
  AppNavigator.router.getActionForPathAndParams("Home")
);

const navigationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const newState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state);
  return newState || state;
};

export default navigationReducer;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming you integrated react-navigation with Redux?

Comment: Can you paste the code of custom header?